# RoR compare timestamp symbol to Time.now date in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do something like this in my controller:

```
@inventory_items = @store.inventory_items.where(:updated_at < Time.now - 1.minute)
```

I keep getting a `comparison of Symbol with Time failed` error.

I tried to call to_datetime and to_date on `:updated_at`, but perhaps those only work on strings or integers?

How can I get `:updated_at` into a proper date format to compare with `Time.now - 1.minute`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was about to post an answer, and Vinodadhikary beat me to it. I'll just add that you might like to check out the [`Squeel` gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel), which I believe would allow you to do exactly what you are attempting (with some minor syntax alteration). I have not used this gem, personally, but it appears to be capable of handling your expression legally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think with the hash style you can use less than or greater than checks.  Try the following:

```
@inventory_items = @store.inventory_items.where('inventory_items.updated_at < ?', Time.now - 1.minute)
```

As far as "proper date format" is concerned, you need not worry about them here.  All database dates are by default converted to UTC.

Comment: Edited this comment, second error is another part of my method. I think this will work, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are some ways you can do it.

The reason it doesn't work is because the symbol is only a pointer to the column and not the column itself.

So, either you do

```
@inventory_items = @store.inventory_items.where(["updated_at < ?", Time.now - 1.minute])
```

or as an alternative

```
@inventory_items = @store.inventory_items.where(["updated_at < :one_minute_ago", {one_minute_ago: Time.now - 1.minute]})
```

Or, you could do

```
@inventory_items = @store.inventory_items.where.not(:updated_at => Time.now - 1.minute..Time.now)
```